# SQL BCP Unknown Error while attempting to read format file on Ubuntu

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp, sqlcmd

I'm trying to automate some importing jobs to my SQL Server database and have the following XML format file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <RECORD>  
    <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="11" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" />  
    <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="30" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" />
    <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="2" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" />
    <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="2" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" />
    <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="2" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" />
    <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="1" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" />
    <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="1" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" />
    <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="2" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" />  
    <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\n"/>  
  </RECORD>  
  <ROW>  
    <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="cuit" xsi:type="SQLNUMERIC" PRECISION="11" />  
    <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="denominacion" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" LENGTH="30" /> 
    <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="imp_ganancias" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" LENGTH="2" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="imp_iva" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" LENGTH="2" />  
    <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="monotributo" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" LENGTH="2" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="integra_sociedad" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" LENGTH="1" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="empleador" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" LENGTH="1" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="actividad_monotributo" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" LENGTH="2" />
  </ROW>  
</BCPFORMAT>
```

And it works fine on my local machine running windows 10 if I run the bcp command

> bcp myDB.dbo.myTable IN File.txt -f File.xml -U x -P x -S myIp

But the problem is that I need to leave this commands running on a remote machine running on Ubuntu and when I do I get the following error

> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Format File : Unknown error occurred while attempting to read.

And I have no Idea why this is happening, I tried changing permissions on the file and running as root but nothing changes.

Comment: See what `file File.xml` gives you. The problem may be the encoding of the file -- Windows likes adding byte order markers to Unicode files, while Unix machines don't like those at all (and `bcp` likely just relies on what the standard library does) If the issue is a BOM or unsupported encoding, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/381230) for details.

Comment: Thanks for your response but this doesn't seem to be the problem since file returns  XML 1.0 document, ASCII text

Comment: @FelipeCurti Did you managed to make it work? I'm facing similar problem.

Comment: Nope, Sadly it seems like BCP on Linux doesn't work the same as in Windows